# nativescript-socketio does not connect to Node Js server

Tags: node.js, sockets, nativescript, nativescript-plugin

I am trying to connect to the server socket (Node Js) and I am unable to do so.

You did the tutorial at https://socket.io/get-started/chat/ and it works correctly. But, when I do it by nativescript or a web client like https://www.websocket.org/echo.html it doesn't connect.

**Node Js**

```
var app = require('express')();
var http = require('http').createServer(app);
var io = require('socket.io')(http);

// this is the culprit:
app.get('/', function(req:any, res:any){
  res.sendFile(__dirname+"/index.html")
});  

io.on('connection', function(socket:any){
    console.log('a user connected');   
    socket.on('chat message', function(msg:any){
      console.log('message: ' + msg);
    });
  });                

http.listen(3001, function(){
  console.log('listening on',3001);  
})
```

**Index.html** Example from socket.io

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Socket.IO chat</title>
    <style>
      * { margin: 0; padding: 0; box-sizing: border-box; }
      body { font: 13px Helvetica, Arial; }
      form { background: #000; padding: 3px; position: fixed; bottom: 0; width: 100%; }
      form input { border: 0; padding: 10px; width: 90%; margin-right: .5%; }
      form button { width: 9%; background: rgb(130, 224, 255); border: none; padding: 10px; }
      #messages { list-style-type: none; margin: 0; padding: 0; }
      #messages li { padding: 5px 10px; }
      #messages li:nth-child(odd) { background: #eee; }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <ul id="messages"></ul>
    <form action="">
      <input id="m" autocomplete="off" /><button>Send</button>
    </form>
    <script src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.js"></script>
<script>
  $(function () {
    var socket = io();
    $('form').submit(function(e){
      e.preventDefault(); // prevents page reloading
      socket.emit('chat message', $('#m').val());
      $('#m').val('');
      return false;
    });
  });
</script>
  </body>
</html>
```

**Main-page.ts**

```
import { SocketIO, connect } from 'nativescript-socketio';

const server = "http://my-domain";

connect(server);

socketIO = new SocketIO(server);

socketIO.connect();

socketIO.on("error", error => {
  console.log("A2", error)
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you've forgotten to specify the port in your `main-page.ts`

`const server = "http://my-domain:3001";`